# Adding groups via Script in powershell Forms.ListView

Tags: forms, user-interface, listview, powershell

I need adding a group of items in ListView but `$listView1.groups.add("groupName")` does not work !

```
$button1.add_click({
    # add group
        $listView1.groups.add("groupName") # Not Work
    # add items
    1..3 | %{
        $listView1.items.add("Item : $_") # work fine
    }
})
```

[image]

full code

```
#requires -version 2
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Drawing'
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms'

#region $form1
$form1 = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
$form1.SuspendLayout()

    #region $listView1
    $listView1 = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView'
    $listView1.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill
    $listView1.View = [System.Windows.Forms.View]::Tile
    $listView1.Size = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Drawing.Size' -ArgumentList @(250, 200)
    $listView1.BeginUpdate()

        #region $listViewGroup1
        $listViewGroup1 = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewGroup'
        $listViewGroup1.Header = 'Group 1'

            #region $listViewItem1
            $listViewItem1 = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem'
            $listViewItem1.Text = 'Item 1'
            #endregion $listViewItem1

            $listViewItem1.Group = $listViewGroup1

            #region $listViewItem2
            $listViewItem2 = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem'
            $listViewItem2.Text = 'Item 2'
            #endregion $listViewItem2

            $listViewItem2.Group = $listViewGroup1

        #endregion $listViewGroup1

        [System.Void]$listView1.Groups.Add($listViewGroup1)
        [System.Void]$listView1.Items.Add($listViewItem1)
        [System.Void]$listView1.Items.Add($listViewItem2)

        #region $listViewGroup2
        $listViewGroup2 = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewGroup'
        $listViewGroup2.Header = 'Group 2'

            #region $listViewItem3
            $listViewItem3 = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem'
            $listViewItem3.Text = 'Item 3'
            #endregion $listViewItem3

            $listViewItem3.Group = $listViewGroup2

        #endregion $listViewGroup2

        [System.Void]$listView1.Groups.Add($listViewGroup2)
        [System.Void]$listView1.Items.Add($listViewItem3)

    $listView1.EndUpdate()
    #endregion $listView1

    [System.Void]$form1.Controls.Add($listView1)

    #region $button1
    $button1 = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
    $button1.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Bottom
    $button1.Text = 'Add Group'
    $button1.add_click({
      # add group
          $listView1.groups.add("groupName") # Not Work
      # add items
      1..3 | %{
          $listView1.items.add("Item : $_") # work fine
      }
    })
    #endregion $button1

    [System.Void]$form1.Controls.Add($button1)

$form1.ResumeLayout($false)
$form1.PerformLayout()
#endregion $form1

#region GUI Startup
$form1.ShowDialog()
#endregion GUI Startup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is necessairy of build an object like :

```
    #region $listViewGroup1
    $listViewGroup1 = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewGroup'
    $listViewGroup1.Header = 'Group 3211'
    [System.Void]$listView1.Groups.Add($listViewGroup1)

        $listViewItem1 = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem'
        $listViewItem1.Text = 'Item 3211'
        $listViewItem1.Group = $listViewGroup1
        [System.Void]$listView1.Items.Add($listViewItem1)

        $listViewItem2 = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem'
        $listViewItem2.Text = 'Item 3212'
        $listViewItem2.Group = $listViewGroup1
        [System.Void]$listView1.Items.Add($listViewItem2)
```